# Why is this sample of input in oop not returning the expected value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, input, return

```
class Questionare:
    def ask_age(self):
        try:
            age = int(input('Type your age after the arrow -> '))
            self.age = age
            print(['inside'], self.age)
            return self.age
        except ValueError:
            print('Only use numbers to inform your age!')
            self.ask_age()

    def __init__(self):
        self.age = self.ask_age()
        print(['__init__'], self.age)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_data = Questionare()
    print(['outside'], user_data.age)
```

Why is it habing such behavior? the result inside is "ok", but the output returns None. What goes on?

```
Type your age after the arrow -> a
Only use numbers to inform your age!
Type your age after the arrow -> 12
['inside'] 12
['__init__'] None
['outside'] None
```

Comment: You should not use recursion here. Use a `while` loop instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return` the value from the recursive call when a `ValueError` happens:

```
class Questionare:
    def ask_age(self):
        try:
            age = int(input('Type your age after the arrow -> '))
            self.age = age
            print(['inside'], self.age)
            return self.age
        except ValueError:
            print('Only use numbers to inform your age!')
            return self.ask_age()   # return here
```

Note: using recursion like this is usually not the right approach. Use a loop instead.

Also, you're already assigning to `self.age` inside the `ask_age` method. You don't necessarily need to return anything & assign again within `__init__`. Assign at only one place.

Comment: Do you mean using while True with try except inside, and in except ValueError, instead of using "return self.ask_age()", I should be using "continue"?

Comment: Something like that. See this question for pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response